# Write raster with its attribute table and symbology

Tags: python, raster, gdal, r, symbology

I am classifying lots of rasters and I'd like to automate the legend creation and symbology displaying for easy manipulation.

Here is the kind of raster I'm dealing with:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] = 1
r[51:100] = 3
r[3:6, 1:5] = 5
r <- ratify(r)

rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$landcover <- c('Pine', 'Oak', 'Meadow')
rat$class <- c('A1', 'B2', 'C3')
levels(r) <- rat
r

levelplot(r, col.regions=c('palegreen', 'midnightblue', 'indianred1'))
```

How could I embed this symbology in the raster when writing it?

Comment: should this have the python tag? looks like straight R from your snippet.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that solution in python are  most welcome... the R code is just for the example.

Comment: What's the question?